# RxJS load and cache first N values when notified and then emit values one by one on next notifications

Tags: angular, rxjs, buffer

I'm building an angular app where I'm trying to implement as much as possible in reactive manner using RxJS.

I'm implementing something like a carousel - where next item is shown on user action. Items are received from BE one at a time. I'm trying to make user experience smooth. So, I want to preload first N items before showing anything to the user.

After N items are loaded - I need to show the first loaded one. When user clicks next - I emit the next preloaded item and trigger preload of the next item to make sure the number of preloaded items is always N.

Kinda buffer - not to make user wait on each step. So, next items are preloading while user is still viewing previous ones.

I was thinking to use something like `bufferCount(N)` on items loading, then spread the array using `map((ar) => from(ar))`. And with another notifier `Subject` using `zip` to trigger emissions from that buffer.. But it doesn't seem to work very well. Looks like every N emissions I have some glitch where I first see one item and then quickly another one.

Not sure how to implement it better. This seems like it should be a common use case.

----Edit----

Items are loaded via http, right.
Here's some code that I have atm (not really functional - just concept):

```js
//..........
// loadRndItem loads data using httpClient
this.loadingBuffer$ =  this.nextItemSubj.pipe(
      // here should somehow trigger first N loading processes
      flatMap(() => this.loadRndItem()),
      bufferCount(this.bufferSize),
      flatMap((ar) => {
        return from(ar);
      }),
      share(),
      takeUntil(this.endSubj)
    );

this.currentItem$ = zip(
    this.loadingBuffer$,
    this.nextItemSubj
  ).pipe(
    map(([val, _]) => val),
    share(),
    takeUntil(this.gameEndSubj)
  );

  //..........
function nextItem(): void {
  this.nextItemSubj.next();
}
```

Comment: Can you show some code you already have?

Comment: Where are the items being loaded from? If it's via http, then you will need some trigger event that makes a new http request. This trigger event will probably come from the user (or a timer) starting to cycle through the items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I managed to get the behavior I wanted.

Might be a bit hacky though.. There's still one subscription here.
Here's the code:

```js
nextItemSubj: Subject<void> = new Subject();

// loading CACHE_SIZE items on init. And load more on nextItemSubj emission
// spread the loaded array into separate emissions
this.itemsBuffer$ = concat(
    from(new Array(CACHE_SIZE).fill(null)),
    this.nextItemSubj
  ).pipe(
    flatMap(() => this.loadRndItem()),
    bufferCount(CACHE_SIZE),
    mergeMap((ar) => {
      return from(ar);
    }),
    share(),
    takeUntil(this.endSubj)
  );

// emit preloaded values one by one when nextItemSubj.next() is called
this.currentQuizData$ = zip(
    this.itemsBuffer$,
    this.nextItemSubj
  ).pipe(
    map(([val, _]) => val),
    shareReplay(),
    takeUntil(this.endSubj)
  );

// when itemBuffer$ first emits (after CACHE_SIZE items are preloaded)
// this will trigger first emission of currentItem$ to display
// and also trigger next item loading
this.itemsBuffer$.pipe(take(1)).subscribe(() => this.nextItemSubj.next());
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you could do it like this:

```
const click$ = new Subject();
const loadMore$ = new Subject();

const buffer$ = concat(of(N), loadMore$)
  .pipe(
    // Unpack the array of results with `concatAll()` into separate emissions
    concatMap(n => forkJoin(makeNRequests(n)).pipe(concatAll())),
  );

zip(buffer$, click$.pipe(startWith(1)))
  .pipe(
     map((result, index) => {
       if (index > 0) { // We need `index` so that's why this is not inside `tap`.
         loadMore$.next(1);
       }
       return result[0];
     }),
   )
  .subscribe(console.log);
```

Live demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-kdh9uk?file=index.ts